# Angularjs how to use one input model to other input

Tags: angularjs

I am showing one checkbox and one input box from a controller array. The requirement is to enable/disable the input box , based on previous checkbox value. I have put ng-disabled=true in second span for testing purpose but it should come from first checkbox value and should enable/disable as per user's input.

here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>    
  <body ng-controller="Controller">

<span>Check: <input type="checkbox" 
  ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'check'" 
  ng-model="x._text"/></span> 

<span>Value: <input type="text" 
  ng-disabled=true 
  ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'value'" 
  ng-model="x._text"/></span>  

<br><br>    
{{string}}
 </body>
</html>
```

And my controller ,

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("Controller", function($scope){

$scope.string = [
    {"_attributes":{"name":"password"},"_text":"password"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"url"},"_text":"mushmatch"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"comments"},"_text":"comments"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"check"},"_text":"true"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"value"},"_text":123}
    ]  

});
```

Code in plunkr

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lXbTNHc3UBI3nepkqstI?p=preview)

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

> I changed your plunker link refer is its ok for you

Comment: No @BlueCloud. This is not what i want. I think you misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a bit o tweaking in your model 
something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/6XlnpXEY3dA5MTyVhohN?p=preview

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

  <span ng-repeat="x in string">

  Check: 
  <input type="checkbox" 
  ng-model="x.attr.check"/>
  {{x.attr.check}}
  Value:
  <input type="text" 
  ng-disabled="x.attr.check"
  ng-model="x.attr.value"/>
  <br>
  </span> {{string}}
</body>

</html>
```

js

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("Controller", function($scope){

$scope.string = [
  {attr:
    {password:"password",
    url:"mushmatch",
    comments:"comments",
    check:false,
    value:123}
  },
  {attr:
    {password:"password2",
    url:"mushmatch3",
    comments:"commentsdsds",
    check:false,
    value:12356}
  }
    ]  

});
```

Comment: This is bad idea. You changed the input itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1:

You need to extract checkbox to separate variable.

**script.js**

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("Controller", function($scope){

$scope.check = {"_attributes":{"name":"check"},"_text":true}

$scope.string = [
    {"_attributes":{"name":"password"},"_text":"password"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"url"},"_text":"mushmatch"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"comments"},"_text":"comments"},
    $scope.check,
    {"_attributes":{"name":"value"},"_text":123}
    ]  

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Controller">

<span>Check: <input type="checkbox" 
  ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'check'" 
  ng-model="x._text"/></span>

<span>Value: <input type="text" 
  ng-disabled="check._text === false"
  ng-repeat="x in string | filter : 'value'" 
  ng-model="x._text"/></span>  
<br><br>


{{string}}
 </body>
</html>
```

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/LIWHk7i2KfhZWBYRdShG?p=preview)

## Option 2:

If you don't want to change you model, you can find checkbox dynamically

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("Controller", function($scope){

$scope.string = [
    {"_attributes":{"name":"password"},"_text":"password"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"url"},"_text":"mushmatch"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"comments"},"_text":"comments"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"check"},"_text":true},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"value"},"_text":123}
    ]  

  $scope.check =  $scope.string.find(function(element) {
    return element._attributes.name === "check";
  });
});
```

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ot2WAhWzV3EPE7eh4mzU?p=preview)